# Find the points of discontinuity: $f(x) = (x^4+x^3+2x^2)/\tan^{-1}(x)$ if $x\ne0$ and $f(0)=10$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Here is the question:

> Find the points of discontinuity:
>   $$f(x) = 
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{x^4+x^3+2x^2}{\tan^{-1}x} & \text{if} \ x\ne0 \\ \\ 
> 10 & \text{if} \ x=0 \\
> \end{cases}.$$

$\frac{x^4+x^3+2x^2}{\tan^{-1}x}$ being the division of a polynomial function and a inverse trigonometric function (both continuous) is **continuous** at each $x\ne0$ and $10$ being a constant function is also **continuous**.

At $x=0,$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^4+x^3+2x^2}{\tan^{-1}x}=?$$
How do I simplify this?

Comment: L'Hospital's rule should be very helpful here.

Comment: What is the rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying L'Hospital:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^4+x^3+2x^2}{\tan^{-1}x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{4x^3+3x^2+4x}{\frac{1}{1+x^2}}=0\ne 10$$
Therefore, $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 2):

[L'hopital rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) is to take the derivatives of top and bottom and then calculate the limit (with the derivatives rather than the original functions). Sometimes this help. If it doesn't work, just develop $tan^{-1}x$ in [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) and there you probably get the limit.