# Find the points of discontinuity of $ f(x) =\frac{e^x-1}{\log_{e}(1+2x)}$ if $x\ne0$ and $f(0)=7$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Find the points of discontinuity:$$
> f(x) = 
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{e^x-1}{\log_{e}(1+2x)} & \text{if} \ x\ne0 \\ \\
> 7 &\text{if} \ x=0 \ 
> \end{cases}.
> $$

I tried to solve it like this:
 $7$ being a constant functon is continuous and $\frac{e^x-1}{\log_{e}(1+2x)}$ is continuous.(Why???)

At $x=0$, $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{\log_{e}(1+2x)}=???$$
and

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\log_{e}(1+2x)}{2x}=1 , \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=\log_{e}e=1  $$
I am not sure the second one is correct and I couldn't simplify $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{\log_{e}(1+2x)}$

Comment: The method of solution is nearly identical to [this problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374970/find-the-points-of-discontinuity-fx-x4x32x2-tan-1x-if-x-ne0) you just asked.  Away from $0$, $f$ is continuous on its domain because it is the quotient of two continuous functions, with nonvanishing denominator.  At $0$, you can use L'Hospital's rule to calculate the limit, which will not be $7$, so that $f$ is discontinuous at $0$.

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{\log_{e}(1+2x)}=\frac{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}x}{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log_e(1+2x)}{2x}}\cdot \lim_{x\to 0}\frac x{2x}=\frac11\cdot\frac12$$

Comment: Please post it as an answer. It will be more helpful to other users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^h-1}{\log_e(1+2)}= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{e^h-1}{h}}{\frac{\log_e(1+2h)}{2h}}.\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x}{2x}=\frac{1}{2}$$
and $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\log_{e}(1+2x)}{2x}=1 , \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=\log_{e}e=1  $$
Therefore $0$ is the only point of discontinuity.
Originally posted by lab bhattacharjee above

Answer (score -3):

$\log (1 + 2x)$ is not defined in the interval $(-∞,-1/2]$
hence, the function is discontinuous at every points in the interval $(-∞,-1/2] $ also.